# Seperate css for iphone 4 and galaxy note 2

Tags: css

I am trying to provide different css styles for iphone 4 and galaxy note 2 . but whatever i try for iphone 4 also runs on the note 2 and i am not able to provide a different css for it . here is what i am trying to do in the order i have placed

```
@media screen and (min-width : 360px) and (max-width : 640px) and (orientation: portrait) {
    // note 2 portrait code
}

@media screen and (min-width : 360px) and (max-width : 640px) and (orientation: landscape) {
    // note 2 landscape code
}

@media screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 640px) and (orientation: portrait) {
    // iphone 4 portrait code
}

@media screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 640px) and (orientation: landscape) {
    // iphone 4 landscape code
}
```

please help me out

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_displays_by_pixel_density

Answer (score 0):

`max-width` for `iphone 4` should be `480` not `640px`.