# Media queries for samsung galaxy note 2

Tags: css

I am trying to set the width of an element based on screen width. My code works perfectly on desktops and most mobile devices except the galaxy note 2. I've tried this query but to no avail

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px), only screen and (max-device-width: 480px), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
    // my css here
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500229/seperate-css-for-iphone-4-and-galaxy-note-2

Comment: @nsawaya that question you link to does not have any answers!

Comment: @Vector but it has a media query that is working on Note 2 and by mistake on iPhone 4 as per the developer....

Answer (score 1):

**The galaxy Note II will switching the innerHeight and Screen.height during the rotation. The innerHeight/Width and Screen.Height/Width are listed below**

```
Portrait  innerHeight/Screen.Height 615/1280
          innerWidth/Screen.Width   360/720
Landscape innerHeight/Screen.Height 335/720
          innerWidth/Screen.Width   640/1280
```

According to this article 
*http://tripleodeon.com/2011/12/first-understand-your-screen/*
the media query min/max-device-height/width is equal to screen.height/width 
So for Galaxy Note II, my media query is listed below

```
/*  Galaxy Note2 - Portrait */
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (min-device-height: 1200px) and (max-device-height: 1300px) and (orientation: portrait) {
    Code here
}

/*  Galaxy Note2 - landscape Due to the Screen Height and Width is changing during orientation changes */
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (min-device-width: 1270px) and (max-device-width: 1300px) and (orientation: landscape) {
    Code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could target just that phone with a conditional stylesheet. It's kind of like fixing a dent with a sledgehammer but it *will* work. You can [parse the user agent string](http://davidwalsh.name/user-agent-parser) and add a stylesheet for just that phone model.